# How to sort agents in ascending order in Statechart transition condition?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on an agent based simulation for an auction strategy simulation. Here are the details,

I have a population (100) of agents with a parameter budget with a value uniform(70,100) billion Euro.

[image]

You can see the statechart flow in the above image. In the statechart combineBids, I want to rank the first three agents with the lowest budget, and the other agents should exit to the notEligible state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a variable called doSomething instead of your agent type and make it type boolean

```
List <MyAgent> ags=sortAscending(myAgents,m->m.parameter).subList(0, 2);
for(MyAgent a : ags){
    a.willDoSomething=true;
}
```

that code can go on the startup agent where the agents live (probably main)

then you need to add a branch after the combine bids and use the willDoSomething value to take them further down the statecharts or to not eligible state

Comment: This sets the value of the variable willDoSomething true for all the 100 agents. It should be true for the 3 agents with max budget. 

I also tried using a parameter with an int value insted of true. But its the same case.

Comment: yeah sorry, i edited it... a little mistake in the for loop

Comment: but you said lowest budget in your post, and in your comment you said highest budget.. make up your mind